# Maxwell's distribution using Box-Muller transform

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am given the following problem to solve (This text is translated from Russian. So, there may be some translation issues):

> *... Another method to draw from the normal distribution is to draw two independent random numbers from the uniform distribution x1, x2 ∈ [0:0, 1:0). Then apply the following transformation:*
>   $n_1 = \sqrt{-2\log{x_1}}\cos{2\pi x_2}$
>   $n_2 = \sqrt{-2\log{x_1}}\sin{2\pi x_2}$
>   *resulting in two randomly independent numbers n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub> from a normal distribution with zero expected value and unit variance.*
>
> *To change the distribution parameters to other parameters, e.g. the expected value for and the variance to, you should multiply the result of the draw by and add, i.e.*
>   $N(\mu, \sigma) = \sigma N(0, 1) + \mu $
>   *In the equation above, N(μ, σ) is a random variable with normal distribution with expected value μ and variance σ.*
>
> *According to the Maxwell distribution, each component (x, y or z) of the velocity vector **v** is a random variable from a normal distribution with zero expected value, and variance*
>   $\sqrt{\dfrac{k_B T}{m}}$
>   *where m is the mass of the molecule, T is the temperature in Kelvin, k<sub>B</sub> is Boltzmann constant.*
>
> *Your task: Draw 10,000 velocity vectors for the N<sub>2</sub> nitrogen molecule at 300K. Calculate the average length of these vectors, and therefore the average value of the speed of the nitrogen molecule, using the formula:*
>   $\bar{v} = \dfrac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\sqrt{v_{x_i}^2 + v_{y_i}^2 + v_{z_i}^2}$

I am not understanding the relationship of N(μ, σ) with n1 and n2, and how to get to vector **v** from there.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $n_1,\,n_2$ are $N(0,\,1)$ iids. Suppose $v_x,\,v_y,\,v_z$ are $N(0,\,a^2)$ iids, e.g. obtained by multiplying samples of $N(0,\,1)$ by a. By converting from Cartesian to spherical polar coordinates, you can easily show $v:=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$ is Maxwell-Boltzmann distributed (I've borrowed the parameter $a$ from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution)). In particular, $v$ has a PDF proportional to $v^2\exp\frac{-v^2}{2a^2}$ on $\Bbb R^+$. Of course we want proportionality to $v^2\exp\frac{-mv^2}{2k_BT}$, so $a=\sqrt{\frac{k_BT}{m}}$. So:

- Get $30000$ independent samples of $U(0,\,1)$ into $15000$ pairs
- Use each such pair to make two $N(0,\,1)$ samples, so we have $30000$ of them
- Multiply them by $\sqrt{\frac{k_BT}{m}}$
- Group them into $10000$ triples
- Calculate $v$ from the triples as above, giving $10000$ of them, then average

We can be more efficient by multiplying by $a$ at the end. A [not particularly efficient](https://repl.it/repls/PrevailingGrowingClasslibrary) implementation:

```
from numpy import cos, log, mean, pi, sin, sqrt
from numpy.random import random

twopi = 2*pi
m, k, T = 14*1.67e-27, 1.38e-23, 300
a = sqrt(k*T/m)

def box_muller():
    r, theta = sqrt(-2*log(random())), twopi*random()
    return [r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta)]

normals = [z for _ in range(15000) for z in box_muller()]
vs = [sqrt(sum(v*v for v in normals[3*i:3*i+3])) for i in range(10000)]
print(f'In SI units, a={a} while vbar={a*mean(vs)}')
```

You can actually show with some calculus that the exact result is $\sqrt{\frac{8k_BT}{\pi m}}$, which is very close to what we get.